# A problem concerning real functions

Tags: calculus

What are the all possible values of $r$ such that there is a function $f : \Bbb{R}\longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$ such that for any $x$, $$f''(x) > f'(x) + r$$ and $$f'(x) > f(x) + r$$ ??

Answer (score 1):

Leaving it to you to fill in the details, but (barring a mistake) the following approach seems to work.

1. Show that the choice $f(x)=e^{2x}$ works, whenever $r\le0$.
2. If $r>0$, then, assuming that a suitable function $f(x)$ exists, consider the function $$g(x)=f'(x)-f(x).$$ Show that $g'(x)>r$ for all $x$. With the aid of mean value theorem show that $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}g(x)=-\infty.$$ Then find a contradiction.